# FirebaseException: An internal error has occured. [ CONFIGURATION_NOT_FOUND ]

Tags: android, google-app-engine, firebase, firebase-authentication

I was able to do google sigin successfully, when I pass token to firebase it returns

```
com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occured. [ CONFIGURATION_NOT_FOUND ]
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzafg.zzes(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzafd$zzg.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzafo.zzet(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzafo$zza.onFailure(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzafj$zza.onTransact(Unknown Source)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:458)
```

In my code I have

```
  mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                    // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                    // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
```

Comment: how are you instantiating `credential`?