# Flutter: FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ CONFIGURATION_NOT_FOUND ]

Tags: flutter, dart

I was able to do google sigin successfully, when I pass token to firebase it returns :

```
W/System  (20511): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
I/flutter (20511): [firebase_auth/unknown] com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ CONFIGURATION_NOT_FOUND ]
```

My json file is quite good.
I implement :

```
final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  String email;
  String password;

RoundButton(
                title: 'register',
                color: Colors.blueAccent,
                onPressed: () async {
                  try {
                    final newUser = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                        email: email, password: password);
                    if (newUser != null) {
                      Navigator.pushNamed(context, ChatScreen.id);
                    }
                  } catch (e) {
                    print(e);
                  }
                })
```

Comment: Does the answer help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41174154/9609442?

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Comment: Is your `google-services.json` in android/app folder?

Comment: Yes. It is in android/app folder

Comment: Have you enabled `Email/Password` in firebase>authentication>sign-in method?

Comment: Yes. I have enabled

Comment: Email/Password was the problem for me. Thx @Jake4142 !

Answer (score 7):

This can be caused by a disabled Email/Password sign in, which is disabled by default. Enable on the Authentication section in firebase console as shown below.[image]

Comment: This works for me. You have to enable the auth method first before you can use it.

Comment: This worked for me. you need to enable the sig- in  methods of your choice

Answer (score 0):

My solution was different because I had to change the Firebase project I was using and therefore swap out the google-services.json file in my project.

I realized it kept trying to communicate with the old Firebase project so I had to delete app/build and run the project again. I restarted VSCode too, but I don't know if that is necessary.

Hope this helps anyone else that was in my situation.

Answer (score 0):

because sign-in Authentication using [email-password] is disabled by default
so go to flutter console ==> Authentication(https://console.firebase.google.com/project/chat-app-c29e1/authentication/users) ==> Native providers ==> cilck on email/password (enable it)
then rerun your flutter project