# Why does my stream end unexpectedly when logging in with Firebase Authentication in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase Authentication for login in my Flutter app. It shows [`CircularProgressIndicator`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/CircularProgressIndicator-class.html) (it shows it when loading) for a long time. It then shows the following error in the debug console:

```
[firebase_auth/unknown] com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ unexpected end of stream on com.android.okhttp.Address@3015bdb7 ]
```

I googled this error and read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41124178/16124033). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56613801/16124033) says to check if I have the authentication type I want enabled. I checked and it is already enabled. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41174154/16124033) says to check the `project_id` in my `google-services.json` file (I think the location of the file is `android/app/google-services.json`, I'm not sure because the [asker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3580952/parohy) is not using Flutter). I checked and the project ID is correct. Also, I deleted the file and downloaded it again.

I didn't include the code because I don't think the problem is caused by the code.

Feel free to comment if you need more information!

How to fix this error? I would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! That's a network problem. I have tried and checked the network connection.